# Custom URL Scheme for Facebook Login (fb(appID)://) says "Safari cannot open the page because address is invalid" EVEN after editing info.plist

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

Ok so I have this annoying problem which I was never able to fix. I'm trying to add FB Login to my app and I modified the Info.plist file the URL Suffix to `fb(AppID)` (where AppID is the ID number) as well as the FacebookAppID, AND I also added on Facebook developers the "URL Scheme suffix (optional)" thingy, and it STILL doesn't work. Keeps popping that error. I tried on all my iOS devices and on various iOS Versions and does not work on any of these too. I was always trying to enter my custom URL scheme: `fb(appID)://` (where "AppID" is the ID number) and it never worked. How can I register my custom URL scheme and how to make it valid?? Also I tried other URL schemes from other apps' info.plist and also their `fb(AppID)://` one too and they worked and said "Open this page in (app)?", only my own custom URL scheme won't work!! I haven't found any solution to this error so please give me a solution anyone thx!

Comment: could you please provide a bit more details?

Comment: Have you tried use your fb:app in another ios apps? Have you setup completely "iOS platform" in developers.facebook.com/apps panel?

Comment: Facebook Login is already fully registered. I just want to register my URL scheme now. I don't think I have any other details to provide, if I remember something else which I could have forgotten to say in my question I might say it later